# FormData и Argument of type 'Element' is not assignable

Tags: typescript

```
 var form = document.querySelector('#form_data');
 var formdata = new FormData(form);
```

Данный код выдает ошибку

> 'Ошибка' message: 'Argument of type 'Element' is not
>   assignable to parameter of type 'HTMLFormElement'.   Property
>   'acceptCharset' is missing in type 'Element'.'

Как можно решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0):

```
 var form = document.querySelector('#form_data');
 var formdata = new FormData(<HTMLFormElement>form);
```

Надо было сделать просто приведение типов